# Delete data from firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a sub-collection document from firestore using flutter, this is what my firestore database looks like.

[image: firestore database]

I have a logged in user and a page to view all the products that they have created and next to that an iconbutton with:

```
onPressed: () => Firestore.instance
                          .collection('products')
                          .document(widget.currentUserId)
                          .collection('usersProducts')
                          .document(product.id)
                          .delete()
                          .catchError(
                            (e) => print(e),
                          ),
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine, assuming that `widget.currentUserId` and `product.id` match the values in the database (always consider reproducing the problem with hardcoded values before posting here, as it may help you catch problems, and makes it easier to help you). Is there any error being thrown? Anything in the program output that looks like it might be relevant? Are you sure the `...` code is even being called?

Comment: Nothing is outputted, it seems as though it's not being called, i printed product.id and when i clicked the button it printed correctly

Comment: So if you just long something in `onPressed: () => `, does it get logged? If not, the problem is not with Firebase but with you Flutter code. This type of approach is key to creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I highly recommend studying.

Comment: when I do onPressed: () => print(product.id) it works

Comment: Hey Satrogan, put an 'await'  keyword before running the firestore operation and see whether it works.

Comment: So the problem was with the userId and i fixed that and now everything works, the product is being removed from the firebase database, the only problem now is that after i delete it it would only reflect on the app after i hot restart